# How to use Receive-ItemCloneNotification in SPE?

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell-extensions

I have items that have clone notifications.

[image]

Now I want to accept the changes using SPE. 
Can someone teach me how to use Receive-ItemCloneNotification? Can't see any articles that explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples to get you started.

**Example:** The following gets the clone and checks for notifications.

```powershell
$clonedItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{9F158637-52C2-4005-8329-21527685CB71}"
Get-ItemCloneNotification -Item $clonedItem
```

**Example:** The following Accepts the notification.

```powershell
$clonedItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{9F158637-52C2-4005-8329-21527685CB71}"
$clonedItem  | Get-ItemCloneNotification | Receive-ItemCloneNotification -Action Accept
```